# Eloquent solution to needing non-const indexed access of a std::tuple (i.e. std::get<E>)

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic

tl;dr **is there *any easy way* to use `std::get` with a non-const index?**

---

I know this question has been asked many times, but none of the solutions proposed appear to be particularly simple, eloquent, or appropriate for my circumstances.

What I am looking for is this: a painless way of using `std::get<E>`, where `E` is any expression, in order to return a `T&` to a `T` which is known to exist (i.e., is safe from range exceptions, hence circumventing the range safe `std::get`) in an `std::tuple<T>`.

The problem appears to be that the compiler needs to know the type of `std::get`'s `return`, yet I will be hand-entering the data and its types and don't need to be certain of the type. (Perhaps `auto` could be used somewhere?)

My reason for wanting to do this can be explained through the following snippets. I am attempting to create a data container class that you can use an initializer list to populate.

---

1. Point: serves the purpose of allowing mock-initializer lists for tuples.

   ```
   template<class... T>
   class Point {
   public:
       std::tuple<T...> get() const { return data; }
       Point(T... t) {
           data = std::tuple<T...>(t...);
       }
   private:
       std::tuple<T...> data;
   };
   ```
2. Data: designed to hold a dynamic amount of data in a `std::tuple` of `std::vector<T>`, where `T` is each of a set of user-defined types.

   ```
   template<typename... T>
   class Data {
   public:
       Data(std::initializer_list<Point<T...>> data = {{}})
           : columns(sizeof...(T))
       {
           // ???
       }
   private:
       byte columns;
       std::tuple<std::vector<T>...> datas;
   };
   ```
3. Combined, this should allow for this simple format for quick data entry (or future data streaming from an external source):

   ```
   int main() {
       Data<char, int, float> {
           { 'A', 1, 3.14 } ,
           { 'B', 2, 6.28 }
       };

       return 0;
   }
   ```

---

These are meant to later be ported to a library full of useful extensions that process data in ways that make it easy for a non-programmer to enter data and formulas without fuss. The formula half is working, but I'm still having trouble with this half due to the limitations of `std::get`:

```
for (auto d : data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; ++i) {
        std::get<i>(datas).push_back(std::get<i>(data));
        // doesn't work; std::get<N> requires const N to know return type to use push_back
    }
}
```

I find this really frustrating, as it appears most do. I can't replace *datas* with `std::array`s or `std::vector`s because of multiple types; I would like to avoid using `boost` despite `boost::any`; `switch (column) { case 0: std::get<0>(...)... }`  can be used to mimick a dynamic `std::get`, but if I can't hand-enter a case for every possible *n*th column; going through the effort of metaprogramming a new container type solely for this one small purpose seems unnecessarily overcomplicated; and seemingly no other quick-fix solution is adequate for these particular circumstances.

Comment: If `E` isn't known until runtime then how do you expect the compiler to figure out the type of `get<E>(arg)`?

Comment: btw, there is `std::any` in C++17

Comment: Why store `columns` as a runtime value at all?  It is `sizeof...(T)`, which `Data<T...>` "knows".  If you want "for each element of a tuple", or even "for each index into a tuple", this does **not** require runtime `get`.  As far as I can tell you have a vaguely specified real problem that you think you can solve if you had a runtime `get<I>`.  This is known as an XY problem.  Can you polish your question to focus on your real problem, and include your attempted solution and what went wrong as details *not* the focus?

Comment: @Yakk added more specific information. Without storing `sizeof... (T)` how can I count how many types are being given to `push_back` data into each `std::vector`?

Comment: @carson the type `Datas` and the tuples all know how wide they are.  Storing the value separately isn't a help.

Comment: @Brian on the above note, added more information in post. I shouldn't need to know the type - I already know the data will have to be hand entered correctly (`Point <T...>` will always match the data types `T...` of the Data object, `std::tuple<std::vector<T>...>>`.) How can I "tell" the compiler to `push_back` an element to one of the `std::vector<T>`s without needing to know its type?

Comment: @Yakk but in order to store new data, passed as an `std::tuple<T...>`, I need to know how many pieces are in each set of data in order to iterate through and convert the tuple's {X, Y, Z} to *datas*' {X1, X2, ...}, {Y1, Y2, ...}, {Z1, Z2, ...}: for (int i = 0; i < columns; ++i) { std::get<i>(datas).push_back(std::get<i>(*std::tuple<T...>*); }

Comment: "Eloquent"?  Do you mean "elegant"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> tl;dr **is there any easy way to use std::get with a non-const index?**

No, because there isn't even a single way to use it with a non-const index at all. Neither hard nor easy to use.

You could however have your constructor like

```
Data(std::initializer_list<Point<T...>> data)
{
  for (auto&& d : data)
  {
    tup_to_vectup(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>{},
      datas, d.data);
  }
}
```

with a small helper like

```
template<std::size_t ... I, class VecTup, class Tup>
void tup_to_vectup(std::index_sequence<I...>, VecTup&& vt, Tup&& t)
{
  int a[] = {
    0, (std::get<I>(vt).push_back(std::get<I>(t)), 0)...
  };
  (void)a;
}
```

because you actually do not need non-const indices here. Your class template arguments `...T` determine the indices at compile time. You just need to convert them into an index sequence and use that to iterate over your tuples.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's where my disconnect was - I didn't know about `std::make_index_sequence`, which is the key to this whole problem. I also need to read up on rvalue refs...

Answer (score 2):

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t,I>;

template<std::size_t...Is, class F>
void for_each_from_indexes( std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f ){
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(void(
    f(index_t<Is>{})
  ),0)...};
}
template<std::size_t N, class F>
void for_each_index( F&& f ){
  for_each_from_indexes( std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, std::forward<F>(f) );
}
```

Now we can invoke a lambda at compile time with a set of indexes.

```
template<class...Ts>
void add_data(std::tuple<Ts...> const& data){
  for_each_index<sizeof...(Ts)>([&](auto i){
    std::get<i>(datas).push_back(std::get<i>(data));
  });
}
```

`i` turned to index is not run time, but compile time, here.

Requires C++14, but it is 2016.

There may be typos.

Comment: I chose Pixelchemist's answer, but yours definitely receives an honorable mention, and I can definitely work wit that snippet. Thank you so much!

Comment: @CarsonWilber: Both approaches are actually related / similar in a sense but this solution is more generic than mine and would be a better choice with respect to the intention to write a library.

Comment: Actually, it seems VS15 still lacks support for this (`std::get...expected compile-time constant expression`.) I'll have to figure something else out.

Comment: @carson `decltype(i)::value` or `decltype(i){}` instead of `i`.

Comment: I stand corrected. Interesting! Why is it decltype is needed?

Comment: @carson because Msvc isn't letting us call a `constexpr` method of a non-`constexpr` object in a `constexpr` context, even if it does not depend on the object state.  The decltype is a workaround the flaw in the compiler.